# HIP RT checkbox grayed out and unclickable in Blender 3.6 (EndeavourOS)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

I'm using an AMD Radeon RX 6600 XT with Blender, and the HIP RT (Experimental) checkbox in the preferences is grayed out and unclickable, making it impossible to enable HIP RT. Using Blender 3.6 on EndeavourOS.